# How can I determine what URL an app is accessing?

Tags: security

I have an app that downloads mp3 files.  The app does not tell you where it is getting these files from.  Is there an Android tool/app I can use to figure out what URL an app is accessing from my phone?

Thanks

Comment: What is this app?

Comment: Its an 'old time radio' app, but I was hoping to figure out how to determine what connections apps make from my phone in general.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, tcpdump. Why didn't I think of that before?

Comment: I was going to recommend Sharkbit, but I couldn't see the URL of the connection. Anyhow, please add a link to the app you used, and don't forget to mark your own answer as Answer. :)

Comment: Please don't add comments as answers. Use actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @ce4 Red Cricket is actually answering his own question. It's a poor answer, but I assume he went with tcpdump to find the URLs / IP addresses.

Comment: Ok, got it. He's right, but extracting links from tcpdumps only works for unencrypted traffic